# How do I set a program to run on startup and how desktop application's login check done

Tags: python, postgresql, authentication, exe, app-startup

I have a small application built using python and tkinter, and I want  that application to run on startup.
Here I have few questions

- My question is how do I actually set the app to run at startup.
- My application needs to login, but I don't understand how I can connect, application with database without placing database credentials in user's downloaded application.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points here:

- how to set-up an application to run at start-up?

  If what you call startup if the machine startup before any user logs in, then the answer will depend on the OS. You will have rc scripts on Unix (and Unix-like) systems, or services on Windows.
- how can an unattented application connect to the database?

  A common way is to have the application run under a dedicated login (user name). Then you configure the database to accept passwordless connections from that specific login on that specific machine (ideally the same one). Of course that login should have the less possible privileges...

Comment: The application will start once user logged in and I need my application to start automatically once user logged in to his computer.
- I do want to use the same login credentials he used to sign up on our web application. Is there any way around to do this, without restAPI?

Comment: As a user, I would not like at all that an application starts automatically on **my** machine and uses **my** credentials without any warning... This is indeed common in corporate environment (but it not the user's machine, it is the company one). Maybe you should review the whole process on a *who is accountable for what* point of view...

Comment: On a more technical aspect, it will certainly depend on the OS. No doubt it can be done on Windows, Linux and OSX, as well as on Android and iPadOS. But you will have to provide a different installation procedure per client OS.

Comment: what could be the best way to make installable exe, I was using pyinstaller till now, but we can't control the installable process in that.

Comment: Pyinstaller only convert a Python application into an self contained executable. If you want to control the installation process you will have to provide an installer. On Windows InnoSetup can be used to build installers, but it can only target Windows systems. Installer procedures exists for all major platform but again each platform has its own procedures.

Answer (score 0):

What platform do you want to do?

On Windows you can set your built (maybe .exe) in Task Scheduler.

> press Start logo and Call Task Scheduler

[image]

> Open it and Create task

[image]

and then setup what app do you want to run in Action tab and don't forget to Naming in General tab

On Linux I used to see somepeople follow this step you can follow from this link below :
[How to Schedule Tasks on Linux: An Introduction to Crontab Files](https://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/)

Or you can search for Crontab to see how to setup task with Crontab commands

Comment: the application will be installed in user's laptop and I want it to be done programmatically, instead of every user doing it manually.